# Porting threads from QT3 to QT4

Tags: qt, qt4

I am porting an application from QT3 to QT4, and keep running into problems when a thread is updating a QProgressDialog. The original code was roughly designed like so:

```
class ScanProcess : QObject{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  QProgressDialog* progress;
private:
  ScanProcessThread* thread;
};

class ScanProcessThread : QThread {
Q_OBJECT
public:
  void run();
};
```

This is after running qt3to4 and making the appropriate changes from the QT Porting guide.

In the original design, inside the ScanProcessThread:

```
void ScanProcessThread::run(){
//...
ProgressInfo *prog = new ProgressInfo(); //then fill it in
QCustomEvent* progEvent = new QCustomEvent(QEvent::User+1, (void*)prog);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(parent, progEvent);//Parent is pointer to the ScanProcess
//...
}

void ScanProcess::customEvent(QCustomEvent *e){
  if(e->type() == QEvent::User+1){
    //update QProgressDialog
    progres->setValue(prog.index);//Value from the ProgressInfo passed above
    //This line crashes deep in ntdll, but I have traced it to the QProgressDialog::repaint()
  }
}

struct ProgressInfo {int count; int index; QString text;};
```

So, that's the important code. The call to QProgressDialog::Repaint seems to always crash somewhere deep in ntdll. I have tried two other methods: 
1) Use QCoreApplication::postEvent()
2) Pass the QProgressDialog* and let ScanProcessThread update it directly. In every case, it's the QProgressDialog::repaint() that fails. Any ideas?

(qt4.4, windows xp sp3, Visual Studio 2008/)

Comment: Just a note, but I would make my own custom event class to convey the progress information, instead of casting to void and back.  You have a potential memory leak if the object you are posting to doesn't delete the pointer, which the code you posted doesn't.  Also, there is nothing to free the memory if the class posted to goes away before processing the events, or if a derived class overrides it and forgets to do so, or...

Comment: @cjhuitt I would do many things differently if I had written the app myself :) That said, this code does take care of cleaning its own pointers up in the customEvent (I forgot to add that line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since only the main thread can access the GUI, you have to be sure that you're handling the `ScanProcess::customEvent()` routine in the main thread.  Usually the easiest way is to make sure that any thread that emits or handles signals have it's [own event loop](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/threads-qobject.html#per-thread-event-loop).

Comment: I agree, the crash makes me think that the ScanProcess class isn't instantiated in the main thread, but in some other thread.

Comment: Why does QT require GUI updates to happen in the main thread?

Comment: @David Souther: the GUI routines aren't thread-safe.  it's very hard to do, given that in most OS the GUI calls have a lot of hidden local state indexed 'per process' instead of using some finer granularity, making the whole GUI API non thread-safe

Comment: Fair enough. I come from a Java background, which doesn't impose those restrictions, and yes, I've seen foot-shots from misusing Java GUI classes that way :)

Comment: Working with it a bit more, I am able to use QProgressDialog::setLabelText() with no problems. 

Also, @Javier, you mention ensuring that signal emitting and handling threads have "their own event loop" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: (edit: added a link to http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/threads-qobject.html#per-thread-event-loop)